# unable to create an OVA in virtualbox using packer with private_key authentication

Tags: packer

I am unable to create an OVA using packer in virtualbox with id_rsa.From the host machine I am able to ssh to the vbox host using same private key. The error is as given

> "Error waiting for SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to
>   authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods
>   remain".  Using "`ssh_password`" the OVA is created successfully. But
>   my objective is to create an OVA using private key.

```
{  
"builders": [{
    "type": "virtualbox-ovf",
    "source_path": "/root/Documents/OVA_idrsa.ova",
    "ssh_username": "support",
    "ssh_private_key_file": "id_rsa",
    "ssh_pty": "true",
    "ssh_port": 22,
    "vrdp_bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
    "virtualbox_version_file": "",
    "headless": true,
    "ssh_skip_nat_mapping": "true",
    "boot_wait": "120s",
    "ssh_wait_timeout": "1000s",
    "shutdown_command": ""


  }]


}
```

I have tried using the `ssh_password` instead. It was successfull. But with private_key file the issue is recurrent.

```
{  
"builders": [{
    "type": "virtualbox-ovf",
    "source_path": "/root/Documents/OVA_idrsa.ova",
    "ssh_username": "support",
    "ssh_private_key_file": "id_rsa",
    "ssh_pty": "true",
    "ssh_port": 22,
    "vrdp_bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
    "virtualbox_version_file": "",
    "headless": true,
    "ssh_skip_nat_mapping": "true",
    "boot_wait": "120s",
    "ssh_wait_timeout": "1000s",
    "shutdown_command": ""


  }]


}
```

**Error**:

> "Error waiting for SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to
>   authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods
>   remain"

Comment: Why do you skip NAT mapping?

Comment: Unles NAT mapping is skiiped, the builder will use the dynamic port for ssh instead of defined port 22. Eventually, we will get this error on using NAT mapping false.
2019/02/07 20:21:05 packer: 2019/02/07 20:21:05 [DEBUG] TCP connection to SSH ip/port failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4214: connect: connection refused
2019/02/07 20:21:10 packer: 2019/02/07 20:21:10 [DEBUG] TCP connection to SSH ip/port failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4214: connect: connection refused

Comment: The problem is not the NAT'ing. You can't ssh from the host to the VM on the standard VirtualBox NAT'ed network. Which network do you use?

Comment: Disabling  nat mapping resolved the issue.  `"ssh_skip_nat_mapping": "false"`